# Delphi VCL - WM_Touch RegisterTouchWindow(Handle, 0); message won't process when touching panel

Tags: delphi, multi-touch, vcl, wm-touch

I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin, VCL project. I am attempting to move multiple panels at the same time using a touchscreen and the WM_Touch messages generated from Windows. I based it off the example code from Chris Benson's blog: http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2009/11/touch-demo.html

And it does work to a degree, ONLY if I touch somewhere on the background form first, and then drag my finger onto the Panel. The Panel(s) will then move with my fingers if I touch the background first. From what I can tell, it seems like the TForm1.WMTouch procedure will not get called when I touch a panel that is on top of the Form. I don't receive WM_Touch messages unless I touch the form first.

In Chris' blog he calls the RegisterTouchWindow(Handle, 0); in the Form Create. Which I assume is why the procedure will get called when you touch the Form. How would I go about getting the WM_Touch procedure called whenever I touch the panel?

-I tried using the OnClick event for the panel, but that doesn't work since it doesn't seem to register a touch as an OnClick event.

-Is this something that I should use the Inherit class with? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Thank you in advance for any ideas!

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TOUCHINPUT = record
  x: Integer;
  y: Integer;
  hSource: THandle;
  dwID: DWORD;
  dwFlags: DWORD;
  dwMask: DWORD;
  dwTime: DWORD;
  dwExtraInfo: ULONG_PTR;
  cxContact: DWORD;
  cyContact: DWORD;
end;

type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Panel3: TPanel;

    procedure WMTouch(var Message: TMessage); message wm_Touch;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
//==============================================================================

//======================== FORM CREATE =========================================

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //  inherited;
    RegisterTouchWindow(Handle, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    UnregisterTouchWindow(Handle);
end;

//==============================================================================

//========================= WM TOUCH ===========================================

procedure TForm1.WMTouch(var Message: TMessage);
    //==============
    function TouchPointToPoint(const TouchPoint: TTouchInput): TPoint;
      begin
        Result := Point(TouchPoint.X div 100, TouchPoint.Y div 100);
        PhysicalToLogicalPoint(Handle, Result);
      end;
     //==============
 var
    TouchInputs: array of TTouchInput;
    TouchInput: TTouchInput;
    Handled: Boolean;
    Point: TPoint;

begin
  Handled := False;
  SetLength(TouchInputs, Message.WParam);
  GetTouchInputInfo(Message.LParam, Message.WParam,
  @TouchInputs[0], SizeOf(TTouchInput));
  try
      for TouchInput in TouchInputs do
      begin
          Point := TouchPointToPoint(TouchInput);
          if PtInRect(Panel1.BoundsRect,Point) then
          begin
              label1.Caption:='Touch ID: ' + inttostr(TouchInput.dwID);
              panel1.Top:=point.Y-100;
          end;
          if PtInRect(Panel2.BoundsRect,Point) then
          begin
              label1.Caption:='Touch ID: ' + inttostr(TouchInput.dwID);
              panel2.Top:=point.Y-100;
          end;
          if PtInRect(Panel3.BoundsRect,Point) then
          begin
              label1.Caption:='Touch ID: ' + inttostr(TouchInput.dwID);
              panel3.Top:=point.Y-100;
          end;
      end;
      Handled := True;
    finally
      if Handled then
        CloseTouchInputHandle(Message.LParam)
      else
      //  inherited;
  end;
end;
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

> From what I can tell, it seems like the TForm1.WMTouch procedure will not get called when I touch a panel that is on top of the Form. I don't receive WM_Touch messages unless I touch the form first.

Correct, because you are not touching the Form itself, you are touching the Panel that is on top of the Form.

> In Chris' blog he calls the RegisterTouchWindow(Handle, 0); in the Form Create. Which I assume is why the procedure will get called when you touch the Form.

Yes.

> How would I go about getting the WM_Touch procedure called whenever I touch the panel?

You would have to register the Panel's `HWND` instead of the Form's `HWND`.  And do that for every Panel individually.  This is even stated as much in the [`RegisterTouchWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registertouchwindow) documentation:

> **Note** `RegisterTouchWindow` must be called on every window that will be used for touch input. This means that if you have an application that has multiple windows within it, `RegisterTouchWindow` must be called on every window in that application that uses touch features. Also, an application can call `RegisterTouchWindow` any number of times for the same window if it desires to change the modifier flags. A window can be marked as no longer requiring touch input using the `UnregisterTouchWindow` function.

You would also have to subclass each Panel to handle the `WM_TOUCH` message for each panel, since it will be sent directly to each registered Panel and not to the Form.

If you want every Panel on the Form to be touch-capable, a simple interposer class will suffice:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TPanel = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanel)
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWnd; override;
    procedure WMTouch(var Message: TMessage); message WM_TOUCH;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Panel3: TPanel;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

type
  TOUCHINPUT = record
    x: Integer;
    y: Integer;
    hSource: THandle;
    dwID: DWORD;
    dwFlags: DWORD;
    dwMask: DWORD;
    dwTime: DWORD;
    dwExtraInfo: ULONG_PTR;
    cxContact: DWORD;
    cyContact: DWORD;
  end;

procedure TPanel.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  RegisterTouchWindow(Handle, 0);
end;

procedure TPanel.DestroyWnd;
begin
  UnregisterTouchWindow(Handle);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TPanel.WMTouch(var Message: TMessage);
  function TouchPointToPoint(const TouchPoint: TTouchInput): TPoint;
  begin
    Result := Point(TouchPoint.X div 100, TouchPoint.Y div 100);
    PhysicalToLogicalPoint(Handle, Result);
  end;
var
  TouchInputs: array of TTouchInput;
  TouchInput: TTouchInput;
  Handled: Boolean;
  Point: TPoint;
begin
  Handled := False;
  SetLength(TouchInputs, Message.WParam);
  GetTouchInputInfo(Message.LParam, Message.WParam,
  @TouchInputs[0], SizeOf(TTouchInput));
  try
    for TouchInput in TouchInputs do
    begin
      Point := TouchPointToPoint(TouchInput);
      if PtInRect(BoundsRect, Point) then
      begin
        //labelX.Caption := 'Touch ID: ' + IntToStr(TouchInput.dwID);
        Top := Point.Y - 100;
      end;
      Handled := True;
    end;
  finally
    if Handled then
      CloseTouchInputHandle(Message.LParam)
    else
      inherited;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I had a feeling that it would be something like that. I also didn't know about how to register it to the panel. Thank you for the quick and VERY detailed response!

Comment: Hi Remy, What is the individual command for registering a single panel's HWND instead of all panels? I am only wanting to control a small handful of panels. Thanks!

Comment: Then you can't use the interposer approach I demonstrated. You will have to actually derive a new class from `TPanel` and then change only the panels you are interested in to use that class while the rest use the standard `TPanel`. Otherwise, you will have to make the Form itself register only the individual panels you are interested in, and subclass them to handle the `WM_TOUCH` messages, but that gets more involved to manage at the Form level, especially when accounting for window recreations.  Using a derived Panel class keeps things simpler and encapsulated.